# JPA hibernate in clause query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In our project there is a requirement to modify the generated query before it is getting fired.

So we have a custom repository factory which will add the additional parameters to the query.

This is how it is being done now .

We have a Query Delegatte which implements javax.persistence.Query where we intercept the generated Query and add the additional parameters

This was working fine so far with hibernate 4.1.4

Now we upgraded to Hibernate 5.2.2 and jpa 2.2

Basically , we read the parameters and set it back to the Query object.
It works for all types of parameters except List.

```
 private void setParameters(Query query) {
        try {

            Iterator<?> iter = getParameters().iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                LOGGER.debug("Setting Parameter...");
                Parameter param = (Parameter) iter.next();
                Object obj = null;
                try {
                    obj = getParameterValue(param);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.debug("****Exception while getting param value****:" + e.getMessage());
                }
                query.setParameter(param.getName(), obj);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("****Exception in setParameters:****:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

It fails in scenarios where IN clause is used and List is passed as parameter like below

```
@Query("select new com.mypackage.UserInfo(m.usrmstId, m.usrName) 
from UsrMst m where m.usrName in :names ")
public List<UserInfo> getUserByNames(@Param("names")List<String> names);
```

I get the below exception while reading such type of collection parameters .

```
Could not resolve QueryParameter reference [org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NamedParameterDescriptor@63bd748] to QueryParameterBinding
```

Is there any change in hibernate 5.2.2 in the way list parameter is being handled ?

In debug mode  ,I observed that expectedType for org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NamedParameterDescriptor object is String .
Would that be an issue ? Should it not be a List ?

Comment: Have you tried checking whether `obj` is a `Collection` instance and if so, calling `#setparameterList` rather than `#setParameter` or is the error coming from the `#getParameterValue` call?

Comment: The error was while invoking getParameter Value.  I also tried setting the setParameterList , but this method was not available in Query interface. The issue is resolved now after I downgraded hibernate to 5.1.0.Final version

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved now after I downgraded hibernate to 5.1.0.Final version

Comment: There were a number of changes to the `Query` interface, some necessary as 5.2.x included the merging of `hibernate-entitymanager` into `hibernate-core`.  I would suggest if you're seeing oddities like this, open a JIRA so that we can take a look and verify whether its a backward compatibility problem or not.